# Are there any smart tradition dasa?

Tags: advaita, harinam-sankirtan

The Madhwa Sampradaya, subscribing to the Dvaita philosophy, has a renowned tradition of Haridasas. Their primary aim is to sing praises I.e. do Kirtana of Lord Vishnu. The tradition includes famous people like [Kanakadasa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanaka_Dasa) and [Purandara](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purandara_Dasa).

I would like to know whether any such dasa tradition exists in case of smartas I.e. followers of Advaita alongwith the names of famous people of the tradition.